# pnoise2() function in noise module produces SegFault python 3.8

Tags: python, noise, perlin-noise

I am trying to procedurally generate some maps for a game I am working on, and I am trying to use the perlin noise function from the [noise](https://pypi.org/project/noise/) module.

By following some tutorials on the internet, I found out that I had to use it this way:

```py
import random
import noise
from noise import pnoise2

factor = 15 #it doesn't need to be 15, it can be anything different from greater than 1 or lower than -1, otherwise it will return 0.0
oct=1
seed=random.randint(0, 100)


print(pnoise2(x/factor, y/factor, octaves=oct, base=seed))
```

I can pass it the values `x` and `y` but if the factor meets the conditions in the comment, the program will throw a fatal error, segfault, when calling the pnoise2 function. What am I doing wrong?

I am also using pygame for the game, and the exact error I get is the following:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00007fe3247f2740 (most recent call first):
  File "scripts/world_manager.py", line 78 in generate
  File "main.py", line 153 in reload_chunks
  File "main.py", line 257 in update
  File "main.py", line 207 in run
  File "main.py", line 406 in <module>
Aborted
```

Here is the `generate()` function in world_manager.py:

```py
# Generate a chunk at given coordinates using pnoise2 and adding it to the chunk list
    def generate(self, chunkx, chunky):

        # print("Generating chunk at", chunkx, chunky)

        GRASS = "grass"
        MOUNTAIN = "mountain"
        EMPTY = "void"

        floor_void_diff = 0.3
        mountain = floor_void_diff + 0.2

        factor = 3

        floor = {}
        items = {}
        chunk = (chunkx, chunky)

        if chunk not in self.chunks:

            # print("Generating chunk at {}".format(chunk))
            for y in range(chunky * CHUNKSIZE, chunky * CHUNKSIZE + CHUNKSIZE):
                for x in range(chunkx * CHUNKSIZE, chunkx * CHUNKSIZE + CHUNKSIZE):
                    i = pnoise2(x/factor, y/factor, base=int(self.seed))
                    print(i)
                    if i >= floor_void_diff:
                        if i > mountain:
                            floor.update({(x, y): MOUNTAIN})
                        else:
                            floor.update({(x, y): GRASS})
                        spawner = random.randint(-1, ITEM_SPAWN_RATIO)
                        random_item = random.randint(0, len(ITEM_LIST)-1)

                        if spawner == 0:
                            items.update({(x, y): ITEM_LIST[random_item]})

                    elif i < floor_void_diff:
                        floor.update({(x, y): EMPTY})
                    else:
                        floor.update({(x, y): EMPTY})

            self.chunks.update({chunk: {"floor": floor, "items": items}})
            self.unsaved += 1
```

CHUNKSIZE is defined in a settings.py file, and right now `CHUNKSIZE=4`

Comment: The error suggests that the module itself has a bug (at the very least some inadequate error handling). In addition to that, your code itself likely has a bug, one which triggers the other bug. Your question would be easier to answer if you gave a [mcve] rather than a short snippet which contains variables which are defined elsewhere.

Comment: @johncoleman I have now added the function that is producing the problem.

Comment: If you search "pygame segmentation fault" you will get many hits, including on Stack Overflow. This is likely a duplicate question, though I don't know enough about it to be sure.

Comment: @johncoleman I have been already searching that kind of stuff, but I can only find build-related errors, which do not help me with my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found a way to solve this problem, but an alternative. I turns out that the way I was using the noise module breaks it some how, so I started looking for perlin noise functions and I found a pretty good one at https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#Python

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're passing `seed` in, for what is actually the `octaves` parameter. I don't how how this causes a segmentation fault, but a large number would cause the addition loop to take on a wild number of iterations. I don't know that this library (if it's indeed https://github.com/caseman/noise) actually supports seeding, but maybe I'm missing where it's supported.

Further, why not use the `snoise2` function? `pnoise2` (actual *Perlin* noise) creates a lot of 45 and 90 degree bias ([image comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZgCk.jpg), Perlin on top). The "Perlin" algorithm has the iconic name, but it's probably rarely the best choice for noise anymore. The snoise2 (Simplex noise 2D) is more subtle about grid alignment. [This library](https://github.com/lmas/opensimplex) (indirect shameless plug) does generate seedable noise in the Simplex category, and the output is a bit higher quality than the one in the other lib I would say, but a downside might be that it's implemented directly in Python instead of wrapping a potentially much faster C implementation. You would also need to implement octave summation / fractal brownian motion yourself if you were after that effect. The other lib provides it with the `octaves` parameter.

Comment: I tried snoise2 but it made my map look like a lot of tiny islands close to each other and evenly dispersed, and I need big islands far from each other. Anyways, I found another library, called OpenSimplex, which works quite well without the segfault issue. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I think the island proximity issue just needs frequency tweaking. But cool to hear that OpenSimplex worked for you for sure!